# strange grammar of c for l-value (in linux kernel: per_cpu)

Tags: c, linux-kernel

all.

While I was browsing Linux kernel source, I found this snippet:

```
per_cpu(zcache_dstmem, cpu) = NULL;
```

If I look up the definition of per_cpu, it is like this:

```
#define VERIFY_PERCPU_PTR(__p) ({                       \
        __verify_pcpu_ptr((__p));                       \
        (typeof(*(__p)) __kernel __force *)(__p);       \
})

#define per_cpu(var, cpu)       (*((void)(cpu), VERIFY_PERCPU_PTR(&(var))))
```

If I parse the preprocessors, it becomes:

```
*((void)(cpu), { __verify_pcpu_ptr(&zcache_dstmem); (typeof(zcache_dstmem) __kernel _-force *)(__p); }) = NULL
```

I have a very strong feeling that I mis-parsed it, and have no idea how do I understand this snippet.
Any help?

Comment: If it's C, then somewhere, somehow, that macro probably resolves to dereferencing a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Missed one replacement.

```
*((void)(cpu), { __verify_pcpu_ptr(&zcache_dstmem); (typeof(zcache_dstmem) __kernel __force *)(&zcache_dstmem); }) = NULL
```

This is an example of [statement expression](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) within a comma operation. The result of the block is the last expression. I don't know what it is doing with the `(void)(cpu)` part, but `&zcache_dstmem` looks like it is getting set to NULL? Good luck disentangling this further!

Comment: If you look up the context in the kernel source, this variant of `per_cpu` is for non-SMP kernels. Presumably that's why we're ignoring the `cpu` argument. Including it in this way ensures that if the argument was something with side effects (e.g. function call) those side effects still happen.